# How to store and retrieve XML request in oracle db using XMLType

Tags: oracle, xmltype

**I am just writing question and want to answer so that one can directly start using it XMLType**

Answer (score -1):

***This is how you can do:***

```
 CREATE TABLE "TEMP_XMLTYPE"
    ( "DATE" DATE NOT NULL,
    "REQUEST_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    "REQUEST" XMLType,
    "MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    );
    
    insert into TEMP_XMLTYPE(DATE,REQUEST_ID,REQUEST,MESSAGE) values(to_date('22-JUN-21'),'abc123','<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        <soapenv:Body>
            <XML_DATA>XML TYPE IS INTERESTING</XML_DATA>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    ','testing XML Type');
    
    select * from TEMP_XMLTYPE;
```

Just three steps and you are done.